# Tab bar in Master View Controller

Tags: ios, view, uitabbar, master-detail

I have created Master-Detail view controller.
I have replaced Master View that is Table View controller with simple View controller.
Now I have also added tab bar to my View Controller.
But I am unable to create segue from tab bar item to another view using XIB.

Answer (score 0):

For creating segues visually you need to use Storyboards. Otherwise you should configure it in `appDelegate` class.

If you trying to make segues from tab bar items you doing wrong. You unable to do this, segues suppose to be made from buttons and other interface elements, or row tapping, when u click tab bar item you just switch views.

For creating Segues using storyboard, place viewController inside Navigation View Controller, then control+drag from one element to another view, in pop-up window choose segue type.

Comment: Then How can I load another view when user tap tab?

Comment: You need to chose viewController for that tab, and set it through storyboard or programmatically.